# Explanation of class instance declarations

Tags: class, haskell, declaration

I am following a tutorial and found this code:

```hs
data A = B | C deriving(Eq)

class K a where
 f :: a -> Bool

instance K A where
 f x = x == C
 f _ = False
 
call = f B
```

Why do I need `f _ = False`? I get the same result without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simply: *you **don't*** need `f _ = False` here. In fact, if you compile with `-Wall` then the compiler will warn you that this clause is redundant, because the `f x = ...` clause already catches everything.

If the tutorial told you to have that extra clause, well, it's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74799238/1126841), it's *not* necessary.

You might need (or want) that line, though, if you had a slightly different definition, one that does not require an `Eq` instance:

```
data A = B | C

class K a where
 f :: a -> Bool

instance K A where
 f C = True
 f _ = False
```

Instead of comparing `x` to `C`, you can match the argument directly against `C`, then define `f` to return `False` for all *other* values. This makes more sense if there were more constructors that could produce `False`.

```
data A' = B | C | D

instance K A' where
    f C = True
    f _ = False  -- in place of f B = False and f D = False
```